# NHDPlusTools get_waterbodies() returning Spherical geometry (s2) switched on Error: arguments have different crs

Tags: r, gis

I have a shapefile of the entire state of Texas and I am trying to get lake and pond data for the entire state. I got the state polygon by using the tigris::states() and filtered the function.

The details for the file are below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExaCB.png)

Everytime I run the function it returns:

Spherical geometry (s2) switched on
Error: arguments have different crs

Here is my code:

`txwater <- get_waterbodies(AOI= tx)`

and sometimes I will even try to override the CRS by:

txwater <- get_waterbodies(AOI= tx, t_srs=4269)

The current CRS is NAD 83. Any help is appreciated. Seems pretty simple but turns out I cannot find how to troubleshoot.